# Are educational questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, topicality

I saw [this post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/how-effective-is-the-tendrils-of-knowledge-approach-to-comp-sci) in our stack.  It seems to be more about educational psychology and how to learn rather than a direct computational question.  Is this on topic?

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, if the question (like the one you reference) is about learning or teaching *computational science* specifically.

We have a tag [education](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) and it has 6 questions so far.  Two of them have been closed for other reasons, but I think the remaining four are all appropriate.

Comment: Agreed; if it's about learning computational science, it's on topic.